# Select Datetime and group by Datetime Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where it gets the maximum value per day of the month. What I wanted to do is to also get the time of the result not just the date.

```
SELECT convert(date,a.time)  AS monthly, MAX(a.Va) AS monthlyVA, MAX(a.vb) AS monthlyVB
FROM tbl_sample a
WHERE DATEPART(month, a.time) = 10 and DATEPART(year, a.time) = 2018
GROUP by convert(date,a.time)
```

Result I get:

[image: Result]

The results I get above is correct but I want to also view the time not just the date in the column monthly. The datatype of column time is already datetime. Here's the result if I select just the time. What I want to get is only the maximum data per the day of the month displaying the date and also the time.

```
SELECT a.time  AS monthly, MAX(a.Va) AS monthlyVA, MAX(a.vb) AS monthlyVB
FROM tbl_sample a
WHERE DATEPART(month, a.time) = 10 and DATEPART(year, a.time) = 2018
GROUP by time
```

[image: datetime]

Comment: provider your sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: already edited and added some pics

Comment: `I want to get is only the maximum data per the day ` based on what column ? `va` or `vb` ?

Comment: both columns. @Squirrel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `row_number()` window function. `partition by` `dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, a.time), 0)` will gives you the number by day. Here I am assuming you wanted the row based on the maximum value of `Va` follow by `Vb`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
           rn = row_number() over (partition by dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, a.time), 0)
                                       order by a.Va desc, a.Vb desc)
    FROM   tbl_sample a
    WHERE  DATEPART(month, a.time) = 10 and DATEPART(year, a.time) = 2018
) d
WHERE d.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
SELECT a.time  AS monthly, a.Va AS monthlyVA, a.vb AS monthlyVB
FROM tbl_sample a
WHERE DATEPART(month, a.time) = 10 and DATEPART(year, a.time) = 2018
and exists 
(select 1 from tbl_sample b where convert(date,a.time)=convert(date,b.time) 
 group by GROUP by convert(date,a.time) having max(b.Va)=a.Va and max(b.Vb)=a.Vb
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use `CONVERT(datetime,a.time)` in place of `CONVERT(date,a.time)` in your query.

if your requirement something different then could you please send some example data, right now i am not much clear.

Comment: the column time is already in datetime format but when the result I get is not correct.